# How to add same header to every page AND wrap body inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, header

I understand how to add a header and footer to every page, but I am using MDL Lite. This has a header fixed at the top of the page at all times with a slide-out drawer on the left. This requires wrapping all of the page's content inside part of the header.

How would I inject a header that requires an open tag that doesn't close until the end of the page? Below is the syntax for the header. Thanks for the help - I'm at a total loss!

```
<!-- Always shows a header, even in smaller screens. -->
  <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
    <header class="mdl-layout__header">
      <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
        <!-- Title -->
        <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
        <!-- Add spacer, to align navigation to the right -->
        <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
        <!-- Navigation. We hide it in small screens. -->
        <nav class="mdl-navigation mdl-layout--large-screen-only">
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
      <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
      <nav class="mdl-navigation">
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <main class="mdl-layout__content">
      <div class="page-content"><!-- Your content goes here --></div>
    </main>
  </div>
```

Comment: just leave the tag open: anything after will then be inside until the container close is found, then your open tag will be auto-closed. this sounds janky, and is indeed technically invalid (according to a validator), but, it will work and work the same on all HTML5 browsers.

Comment: @dandavis that was my initial thought, but I haven't been able to make it work. When you say leave the tag open, do you mean the tag of the div id where the header file is being loaded from, or the tag at the end of the header file? I've tried both and haven't had any luck. Could it be something with the timing of when the file is loaded?

Comment: timing? ahh. if the content is injected via script, markup hacks won't work as the content will be auto-fixed before it hits the page's dom. in that case, you have to append() everything else into the newly added element. if that were, say, a <main> tag: `$(".page-content").append("main")`

Comment: @dandavis this is so close to working, but I'm not quite there yet. I'm not sure if it's a problem with the method, or if I misunderstood your solution, but the script seems to be unable to target page-content since it's found within the file that's being loaded. Is it possible to target a div found inside of a loaded file, or will I need to rewrite some of the html to place the page-content and main divs on the page with all the other content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thought I have would be to use the PHP `require_once` function twice, once before the content to set up the header, and once after the content to close everything out. So your page template would look like:

```
<?php require_once('openheader.php') ?>
<!-- Content -->
<?php require_once('closeheader.php') ?>
```

**openheader.php**

```
<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
    <header class="mdl-layout__header">
      <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
        <!-- Title -->
        <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
        <!-- Add spacer, to align navigation to the right -->
        <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
        <!-- Navigation. We hide it in small screens. -->
        <nav class="mdl-navigation mdl-layout--large-screen-only">
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
      <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
      <nav class="mdl-navigation">
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <main class="mdl-layout__content">
      <div class="page-content">
```

**closeheader.php**

```
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
```

Comment: thanks so much! I wasted time trying to figure out an alternative solution in JavaScript because I'm more comfortable in that language, but this worked perfectly!